# R xpathSApply --> extracting Attribute gives empty result

Tags: r

I try to parse out the xmlValue for the attribute "NAME" in an XML Document in R.

```
<NN ID_NAME="107232" ID_NTYP="6" NAME="dSpace_ECat1Error.STS" KOMMENTAR="dSpace_ECat1Error.STS" IS_SYSTEM="0" IS_LOCKED="0" DTYP="Ganzzahl" ADIM="" AFMT=""/><NN ID_NAME="107233" ID_NTYP="6" NAME="dSpace_ECat2Error.STS" KOMMENTAR="dSpace_ECat2Error.STS" IS_SYSTEM="0" IS_LOCKED="0" DTYP="Ganzzahl" ADIM="" AFMT=""/>
```

The result should be like this:

```
dSpace_ECat1Error.STS
dSpace_ECat2Error.STS
```

I use this function:

```
xpathSApply(root,"//NN[@NAME]",xmlValue)
```

But as a result, I get just empty "" (Quotes)

What have I done wrong?

Thank's in advance!

Comment: Maybe `unlist(doc["//NN/@NAME"], use.names = F)` or `xpathApply(doc, "//NN", function(x) xmlAttrs(x)["NAME"])`? In your example, you try to select NNs with a specific NAME attribute, not the value of the NAME attribute itself.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out by using:

```
erg<-xpathSApply(root,"//NN",xmlGetAttr,'NAME')
```

There should be a better tutorial for this particular XML-function in R....